# Delete FROM Kunden_ansprechpartner as a left join Ansprechpartner as b on a.AnsPaID=b.AnsPaID where b.AnsPaID=400 and Kdnr = 10088

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

```
Delete FROM 
Kunden_ansprechpartner as a left join Ansprechpartner as b on a.AnsPaID=b.AnsPaID 
where b.AnsPaID=400 and Kdnr = 10088
```

why this Sql-Statemnt does not work;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `as` as it's not a keyword. Also, you need to specify alias of the table which you want to delete from, e.g.:

```
DELETE a.* FROM 
Kunden_ansprechpartner a left join Ansprechpartner b ON a.AnsPaID=b.AnsPaID 
WHERE b.AnsPaID=400 AND Kdnr = 10088
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you need to delete from the table Kunden_ansprechpartner by joining with Ansprechpartner table using the conditions you mentioned, then try the following query

```
DELETE a.* FROM 
Kunden_ansprechpartner a join Ansprechpartner b ON a.AnsPaID=b.AnsPaID 
WHERE b.AnsPaID=400 AND Kdnr = 10088;
```

Comment: Hi @MaxLindner.. please mark this as answer.. Thank you